# How to add a repeat Button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a retry button in a mini quiz game, that reshow the view (question generator), but I want to exclude the last answered question from the random generator

```
-(IBAction)continueQuestion:(id)sender{

[self startQuestions];

}
```

*This code doesn't work though*
my questions are like this

```
switch (questionNumber) {
    case 0:
        questionText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question 1"];
        rightAnswer=8;
        break;

    case 1:
        questionText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question 2"];
        rightAnswer=64;
        break;

    case 2:
        questionText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question 3"];
        rightAnswer= 10.2;
        break;


    default:
        break;}
}
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
questionNumber=arc4random() %3;

[self startQuestions];}
```

So for example if Question 1 was asked and answered, I want it not to be included in the random generation of the next question

Thanks,

Comment: Add some code to your question plz !

Comment: Do you want to hide the button on last answered question? You can do that by `button.hidden=YES`?

Comment: @Amar, I want to add a button that regenerate the view (New Question) but will exclude the last answered question from the random selection

Comment: @user3717316 Okay, wouldn't hiding the button on the view work? You need to check if it is the last answered question getting displayed. If not hide button.

Comment: I tried that ! but if I just hide the button it will keep the same last question , and if I add hide button to the method startQuestion it might bring back the same question by random selection , and it the code doesn't really working either way *check the code in the topic please

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an NSMutable array to store questionNumbers for all answered questions. You need to write to this array whenever you get a correct answer in your startQuestions() method.

Then in your viewdidload(), check if the random number generated is in this array, if it is then call viewdidload() again. Otherwise call startQuestions.